# SQL Azure Export Data-Tier Application & import into local SQL server

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Azure database. I'm able to export the Database using Tasks > Export Data Tier Application. This is successful.

I then try to use Import Data Tier Application in my local SQL server and I get the following error:

> Could not import package. Warning SQL0: A project which specifies
>   Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12 as the target platform may experience
>   compatibility issues with SQL Server 2008. Warning SQL72012: The
>   object [db_Data] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even
>   though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are
>   in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
>   Warning SQL72012: The object [db_Log] exists in the target, but it
>   will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop
>   statements for objects that are in the target database but that are
>   not in the source' check box. Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data
>   Provider: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near
>   'CREDENTIAL'. Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed
>   script: CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [databasenameAzureStorageCredential]
>       WITH IDENTITY = N'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE';

I have SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17289.0 and everything is up to date.

I have read different posts on Stack overflow and done some googling but unsure the best way to move forward. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a compatibility mode differences in your local SQL server DB and Azure SQL server DB. Check your compatibility level and if it is mismatched [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-2017) is the resource to solve that. The error was because you use SSMS version 'X' to generate the bacpac against Azure SQL version 'Y'. Try to generate the same bacpac using SSMS version 'Y' and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have checked following the instructions in the link and as far as I can see they are the same apart from recovery model? I will add an image to my original question.

Comment: Do not attach the screenshots of a given solution. I have updated the answer. Check it dear.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how to check this when exporting using the wizard?

Comment: See this.  http://www.adnanzameer.com/2017/07/sql-error-sql72014-and-sql72045-when.html

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure its the same issue as posted. Post I have been reading are saying its to do with External Resources?

Answer (score 0):

Please download the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) to have the best user experience with Azure SQL Database. SSMS v14 is too old. The current version of SSMS is v17.9.

Remove (drop) the database scoped credential named "databasenameAzureStorageCredential" before exporting the database. The following query should give you a list of credentials created.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_scoped_credentials
```

In general, you need to remove references to external sources before exporting your database.

Comment: In SQL Server Help > About the following is displayed: Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio v17.9.1 Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17289.0 A bit confused sorry as to why it says 14.0.17289.0 in the component table and v17.9.1and V17.9.1 in the overall pop up window.

Comment: Sorry just checked the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017 and 14.0.17289.0 is the build number.

Comment: If you already have the latest SSMS do not worry about those build numbers. Pay attention on removing external references from your database prior to export it. That's key on the error you are receiving.

Comment: I've taken over this project and I don't know why the external references are there. My fear is if I delete them I'm not sure how to add them back in. And if I delete them will this cause an error while I'm backing up the database before I've had a chance to add them back in.

Comment: Script the database schema. This way you can recreate any objects if need it.

Comment: Try to understand first what they need a credential to access a Storage Account. Maybe the use it bulk load data from there.